# Onclick doesn't fire in IE when DOM element created via jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

So here is the jQuery snippet I am using to create a div that I want to click on

```
$("#someID").after('<div style="cursor:pointer; text-decoration:underline; display:inline;" onClick="alert(\'It Worked\');">Details</div>');
```

This Works in FireFox without any problems its just IE that doesn't fire the event.  The div is added right after #someID but the onclick doesn't work.

Comment: Have you tried `onclick` (with a lowercase 'c')?

Comment: ...and if you're using jQuery to add the element programmatically, why in heaven's name use `onclick` anyway? See [`click`](http://api.jquery.com/click/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should add the click handler using jQuery's `click` method, like this:

```
$('<div style="cursor:pointer; text-decoration:underline; display:inline;">Details</div>')
    .click(function() { alert('It Worked'); })
    .insertAfter('#someID');
```

This will work, and will also be much faster.  (The browser won't need to fire up a Javascript parser)

Comment: this is not foolproof. see my answer.

Comment: @Moin: Yes, it is.  What are you talking about?

Comment: So I had tried using after and doing much the same thing above and it didn't work but switched to insertAfter and the solution above and got it to work thanks.

Answer (score 0):

use [`.live()`](http://api.jquery.com/live/) or [`.delegate()`](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) to bind events to elements created after page load (in the future).

Comment: I would agree with this, since live() will bind the listener whether or not the referenced element is already in the DOM or not. I have all but abandoned using click().